# Categories and contents display using JSON in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm having trouble displaying the correct JSON using PHP with MySQL. Had tried many options that I can find but to no avail. So far I managed to get the right JSON structure, but the contents keeps looping the with the previous data. How to fix the double looping of contents?

Using 2 tables - `recipecategory` and `recipelibrary`.

Images of my database:

[image: recipecategory]

[image: recipelibrary]

PHP code:

```
<?php
    require("db.php");
        //fetch category table rows
        $sqlCat = "SELECT categoryName, uId FROM recipecategory";
        $resultCat = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCat) or die ("Error in Selecting" .mysqli_error($conn));

        //create an array
        $recipeArray = array();
        $recipeList = array();

    //Loop category table
    while($rowCat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCat)){

        //Add row to json - $recipeArray
        $recipeArray["title"] = $rowCat["categoryName"];

        //Store category name to $catName
        $catName = $rowCat["categoryName"];

        //Sql statement to fetch contents for every categories
        $sql = "SELECT A.*, B.categoryName FROM recipelibrary AS A INNER JOIN recipecategory AS B ON A.categorId = B.uId WHERE B.categoryName ='". $catName."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Error in Selecting" .mysqli_error($conn));
        //Loop contents row and add to json - $recipeArray
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $recipeArray["Section"][] = $row;
            }

        //Add $recipeArray to $recipeList
        $recipeList["data"][] = $recipeArray;
    }
    //display Json
    echo json_encode($recipeList);
?>
```

JSON result: (only part of my JSON result due to limit characters in Stack Overflow):

```
"data": [
    {
        "title": "Western",
        "Section": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "uid": "7UtP7q",
                "categorId": "sy0Sbt",
                "recipeName": "recipeTitle_1",
                "recipeDesc": "Suspendisse id metus et elit rhoncus molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut egestas, neque a sollicitudin suscipit, felis orci molestie orci, quis consectetur urna magna nec mi. Fusce a commodo augue. Integer maximus porttitor elit. Morbi molestie libero a nibh accumsan tincidunt.",
                "recipeIngredients": "150g (5oz) bulgur wheat|3 tbsp olive oil|1 lemon, zested and juiced|1 small shallot, finely chopped|1 tsp ground cumin|100g (3 1/2oz) kale, very finely chopped|1 x 230g pack sweet vine ripened tomatoes, chopped|1/2 cucumber, diced|handful chopped mint|handful chopped flat-leaf parsley|100g (3 1/2oz) raisins|1 x 225g pack lighter halloumi, sliced into 12",
                "recipeDirection": "Bring a pan of water to the boil, add the bulgur wheat, cover, then cook for 15 minutes. Drain excess liquid and cool.|In a bowl, whisk 2 tbsp olive oil, the lemon juice and zest, the shallot and the cumin. Stir into the bulgur wheat, reserving some to drizzle.|Stir through the kale, tomatoes, cucumber, herbs and raisins, mix well, then season with black pepper.|Heat a frying pan over a medium heat and add the remaining oil. Fry the halloumi for 1-2 minutes on each side, until crisp and golden. To serve, top the tabbouleh with the halloumi and drizzle with the remaining dressing.",
                "userId": null,
                "categoryName": "Western"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "uid": "3nV9jp",
                "categorId": "sy0Sbt",
                "recipeName": "recipeTitle_2",
                "recipeDesc": "Praesent consectetur ex vel est pharetra, sollicitudin convallis nulla dignissim. Duis facilisis accumsan erat id suscipit. Nam sodales tortor nec eros vulputate tristique consectetur sit amet elit. In et ultricies turpis.",
                "recipeIngredients": "150g (5oz) bulgur wheat|3 tbsp olive oil|1 lemon, zested and juiced|1 small shallot, finely chopped|1 tsp ground cumin|100g (3 1/2oz) kale, very finely chopped|1 x 230g pack sweet vine ripened tomatoes, chopped|1/2 cucumber, diced|handful chopped mint|handful chopped flat-leaf parsley|100g (3 1/2oz) raisins|1 x 225g pack lighter halloumi, sliced into 12",
                "recipeDirection": "Bring a pan of water to the boil, add the bulgur wheat, cover, then cook for 15 minutes. Drain excess liquid and cool.|In a bowl, whisk 2 tbsp olive oil, the lemon juice and zest, the shallot and the cumin. Stir into the bulgur wheat, reserving some to drizzle.|Stir through the kale, tomatoes, cucumber, herbs and raisins, mix well, then season with black pepper.|Heat a frying pan over a medium heat and add the remaining oil. Fry the halloumi for 1-2 minutes on each side, until crisp and golden. To serve, top the tabbouleh with the halloumi and drizzle with the remaining dressing.",
                "userId": null,
                "categoryName": "Western"
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "uid": "EzfzGJ",
                "categorId": "sy0Sbt",
                "recipeName": "recipeTitle_4",
                "recipeDesc": "Cras id finibus ante. Sed aliquet vel tellus sit amet luctus. Donec ante augue, suscipit eget blandit quis, accumsan ac est. Fusce eu lorem commodo, maximus nisl non, ornare odio.",
                "recipeIngredients": "150g (5oz) bulgur wheat|3 tbsp olive oil|1 lemon, zested and juiced|1 small shallot, finely chopped|1 tsp ground cumin|100g (3 1/2oz) kale, very finely chopped|1 x 230g pack sweet vine ripened tomatoes, chopped|1/2 cucumber, diced|handful chopped mint|handful chopped flat-leaf parsley|100g (3 1/2oz) raisins|1 x 225g pack lighter halloumi, sliced into 12",
                "recipeDirection": "Bring a pan of water to the boil, add the bulgur wheat, cover, then cook for 15 minutes. Drain excess liquid and cool.|In a bowl, whisk 2 tbsp olive oil, the lemon juice and zest, the shallot and the cumin. Stir into the bulgur wheat, reserving some to drizzle.|Stir through the kale, tomatoes, cucumber, herbs and raisins, mix well, then season with black pepper.|Heat a frying pan over a medium heat and add the remaining oil. Fry the halloumi for 1-2 minutes on each side, until crisp and golden. To serve, top the tabbouleh with the halloumi and drizzle with the remaining dressing.",
                "userId": null,
                "categoryName": "Western"
            },
            {
                "id": "7",
                "uid": "0ex4YA",
                "categorId": "sy0Sbt",
                "recipeName": "recipeTitle_7",
                "recipeDesc": "Morbi vestibulum tellus sed commodo vehicula. Phasellus elementum, sem ut sagittis fringilla, dolor ex facilisis massa, eget accumsan felis ligula sed dolor. Sed interdum lectus nec nisi ullamcorper, et congue tellus faucibus.",
                "recipeIngredients": "150g (5oz) bulgur wheat|3 tbsp olive oil|1 lemon, zested and juiced|1 small shallot, finely chopped|1 tsp ground cumin|100g (3 1/2oz) kale, very finely chopped|1 x 230g pack sweet vine ripened tomatoes, chopped|1/2 cucumber, diced|handful chopped mint|handful chopped flat-leaf parsley|100g (3 1/2oz) raisins|1 x 225g pack lighter halloumi, sliced into 12",
                "recipeDirection": "Bring a pan of water to the boil, add the bulgur wheat, cover, then cook for 15 minutes. Drain excess liquid and cool.|In a bowl, whisk 2 tbsp olive oil, the lemon juice and zest, the shallot and the cumin. Stir into the bulgur wheat, reserving some to drizzle.|Stir through the kale, tomatoes, cucumber, herbs and raisins, mix well, then season with black pepper.|Heat a frying pan over a medium heat and add the remaining oil. Fry the halloumi for 1-2 minutes on each side, until crisp and golden. To serve, top the tabbouleh with the halloumi and drizzle with the remaining dressing.",
                "userId": null,
                "categoryName": "Western"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Chinese",
        "Section": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "uid": "7UtP7q",
                "categorId": "sy0Sbt",
                "recipeName": "recipeTitle_1",
                "recipeDesc": "Suspendisse id metus et elit rhoncus molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut egestas, neque a sollicitudin suscipit, felis orci molestie orci, quis consectetur urna magna nec mi. Fusce a commodo augue. Integer maximus porttitor elit. Morbi molestie libero a nibh accumsan tincidunt.",
                "recipeIngredients": "150g (5oz) bulgur wheat|3 tbsp olive oil|1 lemon, zested and juiced|1 small shallot, finely chopped|1 tsp ground cumin|100g (3 1/2oz) kale, very finely chopped|1 x 230g pack sweet vine ripened tomatoes, chopped|1/2 cucumber, diced|handful chopped mint|handful chopped flat-leaf parsley|100g (3 1/2oz) raisins|1 x 225g pack lighter halloumi, sliced into 12",
                "recipeDirection": "Bring a pan of water to the boil, add the bulgur wheat, cover, then cook for 15 minutes. Drain excess liquid and cool.|In a bowl, whisk 2 tbsp olive oil, the lemon juice and zest, the shallot and the cumin. Stir into the bulgur wheat, reserving some to drizzle.|Stir through the kale, tomatoes, cucumber, herbs and raisins, mix well, then season with black pepper.|Heat a frying pan over a medium heat and add the remaining oil. Fry the halloumi for 1-2 minutes on each side, until crisp and golden. To serve, top the tabbouleh with the halloumi and drizzle with the remaining dressing.",
                "userId": null,
                "categoryName": "Western"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "uid": "3nV9jp",
                "categorId": "sy0Sbt",
                "recipeName": "recipeTitle_2",
                "recipeDesc": "Praesent consectetur ex vel est pharetra, sollicitudin convallis nulla dignissim. Duis facilisis accumsan erat id suscipit. Nam sodales tortor nec eros vulputate tristique consectetur sit amet elit. In et ultricies turpis.",
                "recipeIngredients": "150g (5oz) bulgur wheat|3 tbsp olive oil|1 lemon, zested and juiced|1 small shallot, finely chopped|1 tsp ground cumin|100g (3 1/2oz) kale, very finely chopped|1 x 230g pack sweet vine ripened tomatoes, chopped|1/2 cucumber, diced|handful chopped mint|handful chopped flat-leaf parsley|100g (3 1/2oz) raisins|1 x 225g pack lighter halloumi, sliced into 12",
                "recipeDirection": "Bring a pan of water to the boil, add the bulgur wheat, cover, then cook for 15 minutes. Drain excess liquid and cool.|In a bowl, whisk 2 tbsp olive oil, the lemon juice and zest, the shallot and the cumin. Stir into the bulgur wheat, reserving some to drizzle.|Stir through the kale, tomatoes, cucumber, herbs and raisins, mix well, then season with black pepper.|Heat a frying pan over a medium heat and add the remaining oil. Fry the halloumi for 1-2 minutes on each side, until crisp and golden. To serve, top the tabbouleh with the halloumi and drizzle with the remaining dressing.",
                "userId": null,
                "categoryName": "Western"
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "uid": "EzfzGJ",
                "categorId": "sy0Sbt",
                "recipeName": "recipeTitle_4",
                "recipeDesc": "Cras id finibus ante. Sed aliquet vel tellus sit amet luctus. Donec ante augue, suscipit eget blandit quis, accumsan ac est. Fusce eu lorem commodo, maximus nisl non, ornare odio.",
                "recipeIngredients": "150g (5oz) bulgur wheat|3 tbsp olive oil|1 lemon, zested and juiced|1 small shallot, finely chopped|1 tsp ground cumin|100g (3 1/2oz) kale, very finely chopped|1 x 230g pack sweet vine ripened tomatoes, chopped|1/2 cucumber, diced|handful chopped mint|handful chopped flat-leaf parsley|100g (3 1/2oz) raisins|1 x 225g pack lighter halloumi, sliced into 12",
                "recipeDirection": "Bring a pan of water to the boil, add the bulgur wheat, cover, then cook for 15 minutes. Drain excess liquid and cool.|In a bowl, whisk 2 tbsp olive oil, the lemon juice and zest, the shallot and the cumin. Stir into the bulgur wheat, reserving some to drizzle.|Stir through the kale, tomatoes, cucumber, herbs and raisins, mix well, then season with black pepper.|Heat a frying pan over a medium heat and add the remaining oil. Fry the halloumi for 1-2 minutes on each side, until crisp and golden. To serve, top the tabbouleh with the halloumi and drizzle with the remaining dressing.",
                "userId": null,
                "categoryName": "Western"
            },
            {
                "id": "7",
                "uid": "0ex4YA",
                "categorId": "sy0Sbt",
                "recipeName": "recipeTitle_7",
                "recipeDesc": "Morbi vestibulum tellus sed commodo vehicula. Phasellus elementum, sem ut sagittis fringilla, dolor ex facilisis massa, eget accumsan felis ligula sed dolor. Sed interdum lectus nec nisi ullamcorper, et congue tellus faucibus.",
                "recipeIngredients": "150g (5oz) bulgur wheat|3 tbsp olive oil|1 lemon, zested and juiced|1 small shallot, finely chopped|1 tsp ground cumin|100g (3 1/2oz) kale, very finely chopped|1 x 230g pack sweet vine ripened tomatoes, chopped|1/2 cucumber, diced|handful chopped mint|handful chopped flat-leaf parsley|100g (3 1/2oz) raisins|1 x 225g pack lighter halloumi, sliced into 12",
                "recipeDirection": "Bring a pan of water to the boil, add the bulgur wheat, cover, then cook for 15 minutes. Drain excess liquid and cool.|In a bowl, whisk 2 tbsp olive oil, the lemon juice and zest, the shallot and the cumin. Stir into the bulgur wheat, reserving some to drizzle.|Stir through the kale, tomatoes, cucumber, herbs and raisins, mix well, then season with black pepper.|Heat a frying pan over a medium heat and add the remaining oil. Fry the halloumi for 1-2 minutes on each side, until crisp and golden. To serve, top the tabbouleh with the halloumi and drizzle with the remaining dressing.",
                "userId": null,
                "categoryName": "Western"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "uid": "nEdCe3",
                "categorId": "wNXTav",
                "recipeName": "recipeTitle_3",
                "recipeDesc": "Etiam id elementum sapien. Cras bibendum dolor felis, nec egestas diam posuere id. Vivamus feugiat urna et libero cursus fermentum.",
                "recipeIngredients": "150g (5oz) bulgur wheat|3 tbsp olive oil|1 lemon, zested and juiced|1 small shallot, finely chopped|1 tsp ground cumin|100g (3 1/2oz) kale, very finely chopped|1 x 230g pack sweet vine ripened tomatoes, chopped|1/2 cucumber, diced|handful chopped mint|handful chopped flat-leaf parsley|100g (3 1/2oz) raisins|1 x 225g pack lighter halloumi, sliced into 12",
                "recipeDirection": "Bring a pan of water to the boil, add the bulgur wheat, cover, then cook for 15 minutes. Drain excess liquid and cool.|In a bowl, whisk 2 tbsp olive oil, the lemon juice and zest, the shallot and the cumin. Stir into the bulgur wheat, reserving some to drizzle.|Stir through the kale, tomatoes, cucumber, herbs and raisins, mix well, then season with black pepper.|Heat a frying pan over a medium heat and add the remaining oil. Fry the halloumi for 1-2 minutes on each side, until crisp and golden. To serve, top the tabbouleh with the halloumi and drizzle with the remaining dressing.",
                "userId": null,
                "categoryName": "Chinese"
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "uid": "8NMelb",
                "categorId": "wNXTav",
                "recipeName": "recipeTitle_5",
                "recipeDesc": "Curabitur est massa, fermentum vitae orci a, pulvinar hendrerit neque. Curabitur finibus ante nec dignissim tempor. Proin eget purus augue. Pellentesque quis eros id turpis tristique condimentum a gravida quam.",
                "recipeIngredients": "150g (5oz) bulgur wheat|3 tbsp olive oil|1 lemon, zested and juiced|1 small shallot, finely chopped|1 tsp ground cumin|100g (3 1/2oz) kale, very finely chopped|1 x 230g pack sweet vine ripened tomatoes, chopped|1/2 cucumber, diced|handful chopped mint|handful chopped flat-leaf parsley|100g (3 1/2oz) raisins|1 x 225g pack lighter halloumi, sliced into 12",
                "recipeDirection": "Bring a pan of water to the boil, add the bulgur wheat, cover, then cook for 15 minutes. Drain excess liquid and cool.|In a bowl, whisk 2 tbsp olive oil, the lemon juice and zest, the shallot and the cumin. Stir into the bulgur wheat, reserving some to drizzle.|Stir through the kale, tomatoes, cucumber, herbs and raisins, mix well, then season with black pepper.|Heat a frying pan over a medium heat and add the remaining oil. Fry the halloumi for 1-2 minutes on each side, until crisp and golden. To serve, top the tabbouleh with the halloumi and drizzle with the remaining dressing.",
                "userId": null,
                "categoryName": "Chinese"
            },
            {
                "id": "10",
                "uid": "vOOL8r",
                "categorId": "wNXTav",
                "recipeName": "recipeTitle_10",
                "recipeDesc": "Pellentesque blandit facilisis pharetra. Suspendisse libero lectus, malesuada non enim in, convallis cursus erat. Nunc ac congue odio. Integer nibh nibh, luctus et ornare eget, aliquam sit amet velit.",
                "recipeIngredients": "150g (5oz) bulgur wheat|3 tbsp olive oil|1 lemon, zested and juiced|1 small shallot, finely chopped|1 tsp ground cumin|100g (3 1/2oz) kale, very finely chopped|1 x 230g pack sweet vine ripened tomatoes, chopped|1/2 cucumber, diced|handful chopped mint|handful chopped flat-leaf parsley|100g (3 1/2oz) raisins|1 x 225g pack lighter halloumi, sliced into 12",
                "recipeDirection": "Bring a pan of water to the boil, add the bulgur wheat, cover, then cook for 15 minutes. Drain excess liquid and cool.|In a bowl, whisk 2 tbsp olive oil, the lemon juice and zest, the shallot and the cumin. Stir into the bulgur wheat, reserving some to drizzle.|Stir through the kale, tomatoes, cucumber, herbs and raisins, mix well, then season with black pepper.|Heat a frying pan over a medium heat and add the remaining oil. Fry the halloumi for 1-2 minutes on each side, until crisp and golden. To serve, top the tabbouleh with the halloumi and drizzle with the remaining dressing.",
                "userId": null,
                "categoryName": "Chinese"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Looking at your tables, in category table the data that appears under uId, the same data appears under categoryId in the other table. Is it correct data placement? Do check that out..

Comment: @T.Shah Yes. The categoryId is the one that link which row belongs to which category.

Comment: For the json, the first 'Western' section is correct, the problem comes after the 2nd section and so on..as it suppose to display only Chinese category content, it also displaying the western category content.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM: please do not make edits that embolden whole paragraphs, that's excessive formatting, and harder to read. I've reverted that. Thanks for wanting to improve posts, but if you do, please fix case and spelling errors as well (see my edit).

Comment: @halfer Thank you for your kind reminder for how to properly structure my post. I will do my best to make it easy to read as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. There's no problem to my database tables, what's wrong is the PHP. There's two problems for this. Firstly is the variable for the arrays, secondly is the way how it store data into array in the while loop,

**First Problem**

I declared my arrays as such, there's nothing wrong with this, but if I'm using a function or method to use this arrays, I need to make it global. This way, I can gain access to the variable in any of my PHP.

```
$recipeArray = array();
$recipeList = array();
```

***Correct ways to create a global variable***

Reference: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp)

```
$recipeArray = array();

//call for function
categoryContent()

function categoryContent() { 
    $GLOBALS['recipeArray'][] = $rowContent; 
}
```

**Second Problem**

With first problem solved, still it repeat the data from the previous category, so the simple solution is to use a `unset()` function.

Reference: [w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/unset.php)

```
while($rowCat = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCat)){
    $GLOBALS['recipeArray']["title"] = $rowCat['categoryName'];
    categoryContent($rowCat['categoryName']);

    $recipeList["data"][]=$recipeArray;
}
```

By adding `unset($GLOBALS['recipeArray']);` inside while loop before `$GLOBALS['recipeArray']["title"] = $rowCat['categoryName'];`, I get the final JSON result that I'm looking for.

```
while($rowCat = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCat)){
    unset($GLOBALS['recipeArray']);
    $GLOBALS['recipeArray']["title"] = $rowCat['categoryName'];
    categoryContent($rowCat['categoryName']);

    $recipeList["data"][]=$recipeArray;
}
```